# Are these subspaces of continuous, bounded functions Banach Spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X=C^b(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous, bounded functions in $\mathbb{R}$. $X$, equipped with the norm $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|$ is a Banach space. What can you say about these subspaces, are they Banach spaces, too?

(i) $\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R})=\{f\in X : \exists N\;\forall |x|\geq N \; f(x)=0 \}$

(ii) $C_0(\mathbb{R})=\{f\in X : \lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0 \}$

Comment: The second one is clearly a Banach space, since it is closed in $X$. But what about the first one?

Comment: What can you say about the sequence with terms $f_n(x)={1\over 1+x^2}\cdot\chi_{[-n,n]}$?

Comment: @copper.hat Ah, of course. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMitra the sequence you are talking about is not of continuous functions, so it wouldn't work...

Comment: What about this: 

Let $A_n=\{f\in\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R}):f(x)=0\,\forall |x|\geq n\}$.

Then $A_n\subset\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R})=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty A_n$.

Could we use Baire's Category Theorem?

Comment: Just "smooth out" the functions in my example.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** closure of $\mathcal{K}(\mathbb{R})$ is $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.
$$
\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}
$$